# Letra al azar sin repetir

Tags: javascript, array

soy nuevo en esto y estoy haciendo un juego de Tutti-Frutti, ese que tienes categorías y tienes que colocar palabras a base de la letra sorteada.

resulta el código que hice no funciona y no encuentro la razón, obviamente que estoy errando en algo que no veo o no conozco.

El objetivo es que entregue letras al azar, pero sin repetir, actualmente me entrega las letras, pero se repiten.

Les cuento como relleno porque la web me dice que no di mucha explicación, soy nuevo programando, por lo tanto el objetivo es practicar el for y las funciones, si hay métodos que resuelven ciertas cosas, prefiero no utilizar ese camino, en Java sé que hay un método para comprar arrays, si en JS también lo hay, no lo quiero usar, por eso comparo usando un for.

eso es todo, desde ya, gracias.

```
function resultado(){

//defino variables
var letras = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","Ñ","O","P","Q","R","S","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var yaUsados = [letras.length];
var azar = "";


//esta funcion me entrega una letra al azar
function letraAlAzar() {
    var pasar = Math.floor(Math.random() * letras.length);
    azar = letras[pasar];
    return azar;
}

// ejecuto la funcion... eso creo, capaz que el error está acá
letraAlAzar();

// si la letra ya fue usada, ejecutar de nuevo letraAlAzar()
var usado = true;
for (var i = 0; i < letras.length && usado; i++){
      if ( yaUsados[i] == letras[i]){
          letraAlAzar();
      }else {
          yaUsados[i] = letras[i];
          usado = false;
          }
}

//si todas las letras fueron usadas, terminar la partida y recargar la web
var completo = true;
for (var i = 0; i < letras.length && completo; i++){

      if(letras[i] == yaUsados[i]){
        completo = true;
      }else {
        completo = false;
      }
}

if (completo){
  window.alert("Juego terminado");
  location.reload()
}

document.getElementById('letra').innerHTML = azar;



}
```

Comment: Creo que hay un buen error de lógica aplicada acá. ¿Como sería el funcionamiento pensado de esto? Ahora mismo me entrega 1 letra y se acaba. Hay algo más que deba pasar ?

Comment: cual es el element `letra` ???

Comment: el elemento "letra" es la ID de una DIV en el HTML, donde el innerHTML colocaría lo de la variable "azar"

El objetivo es que apretando un botón, dé una letra, y al volver apretar, no se repita. probándolo, entrega una letra cada vez que aprietas el botón, pero se repiten.

Comment: El último for, no valdría decir que el juego está completo si la longitud de los dos arrays es la misma? COmparar posición por posición no va a dar casi nunca lo mismo porque vas tomando letras al azar. Lo otro, en el primer for llamaz nuevamente al método letrasAlAzar pero no te sales del ciclo. Tienes que salirte del ciclo for antes de comenzar la revisión de una nueva letra, no?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo así:

Dejé todo lo de JavaScript comentado para que se entienda lo realizado, espero te sirva de guía y lo puedas adaptar a tus necesidades.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Letra: <span id="letra"></span></div>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Nueva Letra</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript (archivo app.js en misma carpeta que index.html)**

```
const spanResultado = document.getElementById("letra");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var letras = [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      "D",
      "E",
      "F",
      "G",
      "H",
      "I",
      "J",
      "K",
      "L",
      "M",
      "N",
      "Ñ",
      "O",
      "P",
      "Q",
      "R",
      "S",
      "U",
      "V",
      "W",
      "X",
      "Y",
      "Z",
    ];

//Se usará para controlar cantidad de generados
let contador = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  //esta funcion me entrega una letra al azar
  //Esta función estaba mal
  var pasar = Math.round(Math.random() * (letras.length - 1));
  var azar = letras[pasar];
  //Muestro el valor en un Span.
  spanResultado.innerText = azar;
  
  //Para control de Letra, largo de array y cantidad generados
  contador++;
  console.log(
    "Letra " + azar,
    "Largo Array: " + letras.length,
    "Cant. Generadas " + contador
  );

  //Busco el índice que le corresponde a la letra mostrada en array letras
  const indiceLetra = letras.indexOf(azar);
  //Elimino esa letra del array
  letras.splice(indiceLetra, 1);

//Si se eliminaron todas las letras es decir ya se mostraron todas, devuelvo alerta.
  if (letras.length === 0) {
    alert("Todas las letras usadas");
  }
});
```

Habían varios problemas de lógica, y el random estaba generando mal también, espero te sirva. La variable contador así como toda la parte de control la podés borrar una vez probado todo. Los puse para ver en consola si todo estaba funcionando ok.

Quedo a las ordenes, saludos.

**Otra opción un poco más avanzada:**

```
const spanResultado = document.getElementById("letra");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const letras = [..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
//Se usará para controlar cantidad de generados
let contador = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const pasar = Math.round(Math.random() * (letras.length - 1));
  const azar = letras[pasar];
  //Muestro el valor en un Span.
  spanResultado.innerText = azar;

  //Para control de Letra, largo de array y cantidad generados
  contador++;
  console.log(
    `Letra: ${azar} Largo Array: ${letras.length} Cant. Generadas: ${contador}`
  );

  //Busco el índice que le corresponde a la letra mostrada en array letras
  const indiceLetra = letras.indexOf(azar);
  //Elimino esa letra del array
  letras.splice(indiceLetra, 1);

  //Si se eliminaron todas las letras es decir ya se mostraron todas, devuelvo alerta.
  letras.length === 0 && alert("Todas las letras usadas");
});
```

**Nota:** Otra opción podría ser guardar la letra en un array de usadas, y cada vez que se genera la letra verificar con el método **includes** si esta letra ya se encuentra en el array de usadas, si no se encuentra la agrega y la muestra, si ya se encuentra llamamos a la función devuelta y se vuelve a generar otra.